# Flex: instead of a LinearGradient fill only the last GradientEntry is displayed

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a Rect with the following fill:

```
<s:LinearGradient id="goldGradientFill">
    <s:entries>
        <s:GradientEntry color="#6B4822" ratio="0" />
        <s:GradientEntry color="#FDE3C0" ratio="1" />
    </s:entries>
</s:LinearGradient>
```

But instead of a two color fill only the last GradientEntry color (#FDE3C0) is displayed. In my case there are 3 rects with this fill. One displays the gradient like it should.

The code for alle three rects is the same:

```
var myRect:Rect = new Rect();
myRect.height = 30;
myRect.width = 4;
myRect.fill = goldGradientFill;
myGraphics.addElement(myRect);
```

Is there anyone who experienced a problem like this one?

(update)
I added some screens.

[image: wrong behaviour]
[image: correct behaviour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is due to a limitation of the LinearGradient.
The width of the Rect has to be minimum 5 pixels so that a gradient is displayed.